# background color not changing in iPhone layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change the back ground color of the header....
its working fine in the desktop layout....
but its not working fine in the iphone lay out....
the header color is not changing in the iphone lay out....
providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/mzMjT/embedded/result/

```
<tr>
            <th style="
    background-color: red;
">First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Favorite Color</th>
            <th>Wars or Trek?</th>
            <th>Porn Name</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Dream Vacation City</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
            <th>Arbitrary Data</th>
        </tr>

th {
background: #333;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Add `!important`, e.g. `color: #000 !important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your styles aren't changing the mobile layout is because it's hiding the `th` elements on small screens, and using [CSS Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to substitute for the headers. If you want to style the 'headers' on the mobile version, use something like this:

```
td:before {
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's going to take some tweaking to get the pseudo elements to make a consistent column, but this should get you on the right track!